# how do i add a glow only to the smoke using the compositor

Tags: smoke-simulation, compositing-nodes

i want to add a glare effect to only the smoke but as you can see it applied it to the entire smoke domain when i added a material pass

[image]

Comment: Use a separate render layer for the smoke

Comment: could you elaborate i dont know what you mean by that

Comment: Move your smoke to a different layer then in the layer manger add a new named layer and assign it the smoke layer. When you render you will see the process run once for each named layer. Now in the Compositor you can select the layers as different inputs and filter them/Glare as you need.